# How to "update" from module tf.keras.preprocessing.image to tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory for features extraction

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

This code part is common to both "problematic" codes below:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32
IM_DIR = '/content/drive/My Drive/101_ObjectCategories/'
IM_HEIGHT = 224
IM_WIDTH = 224
NUM_IM = 8686
NUM_EPOCHS = int(math.ceil(NUM_IM / BATCH_SIZE))

#load pre-trained base model
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet',
                 include_top=False,
                 input_shape=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT, CH),
                 pooling='max')
```

The following code I successfully use to extract features of a set of images using module `tf.keras.preprocessing.image`.

```
datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
dataset = datagen.flow_from_directory(IM_DIR,
                                      target_size=(IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH),
                                      class_mode=None,
                                      shuffle=False)

feature_list = []
feature_list = model.predict(dataset, num_epochs)
```

Thereafter I train a simple nearest-neighbor model using brute-force algorithm and I'm able to find three other images that are really similar to the query image as you can see below:

[image: Right results]

But as pointed in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image) this preprocessing module is deprecated.
So, I would like to "update" the code as suggested in the documentation: "Prefer loading data with `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`, and then transforming the output `tf.data.Dataset` with preprocessing layers".
For that I'm trying the following:

```
#load images
dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  IM_DIR,
  labels='inferred', #'inferred', None
  label_mode='categorical',  #'int', 'categorical', 'binary' or None
  class_names=None,
  color_mode='rgb',  #'grayscale', 'rgb' or 'rgba'
  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
  image_size=(IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH),
  shuffle=True,
  seed=51719,
  validation_split=None,
  subset=None,                #'training', 'validation' or 'both'
  interpolation='bilinear',   #'bilinear', 'nearest', 'bicubic', 'area', 'lanczos3', 'lanczos5', 'gaussian' or 'mitchellcubic'
  follow_links=False,
  crop_to_aspect_ratio=False
)

#"transforming the output with preprocessing layers"
#rescale (normalize) dataset
rescale_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)

rescaled_dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (rescale_layer(x), y))
im_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(rescaled_dataset))


#configure dataset for performance
#https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#configure_the_dataset_for_performance

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
tuned_dataset = dataset.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

And now I begin with the features extraction

```
#features extraction
#https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict
feature_list = []

feature_list = model.predict(
    tuned_dataset,
    batch_size=None,
    verbose='auto',
    steps=None,
    callbacks=None,
    max_queue_size=10,
    workers=1,
    use_multiprocessing=False
)

#save features
pickle.dump(
    feature_list,
    open(DATA_DIR + 'features.pickle', 'wb'))
```

After that I do the same and train the nearest neighbor model with this features, but the results are catastrophic as you can see below:

[image: Bad results]

What I'm doing so wrong that I have such different results?

**== EDIT 1 ==**

Answering @DWKOT using the same image we have following results:

```
#Query image with first code
im_idx = 75
distances, indices = neighbors.kneighbors([feature_list[im_idx]])
plt.imshow(mpimg.imread(filenames[im_idx]), interpolation='lanczos')
```

[image: Query image]

```
#Similar image
plt.imshow(mpimg.imread(filenames[indices[0][1]]), interpolation='lanczos')
```

[image: Similar image]

And the code that give us the distance to the 5 nearest neighbors:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(distances[0][i])
```

With the following results:

```
0.0
185.60701
185.75049
195.71657
196.4056
```

With the second code we have following result for query / similar image:

[image: Query image] / [image: Similar image 2]

And following results for the first five "similar" images:

```
0.0
0.81401
0.88622
0.92734
0.9346
```

What is also strange as I would expect similar images having values next to zero and different ones far from zero...

Comment: What are the results if you use the same query image (snoopy) across both models? How can you be sure behavior has changed with two different query images?

Comment: @DWKOT thanks for your comment. You are right, but what I wrote here was just a summary of all tests I've done and we can easily perceive that the images of the second group are very dissimilar from the query image. Anyways I've just edited the question with one more test showing the different results for the same query image.